# How to reference another control in a TreeViewItem through a binding converter?

Tags: wpf, binding, converters

I would like to bind the Visibility of a `TextBox` based on SelectedItem of a `ComboBox`in same TreeViewItemContainer. I think I can use a Converter for the Binding but I don't know how to send the `ComboBox` item as a parameter of the `TextBox` Binding. Can this be done?

```
<TreeView>
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <ComboBox Margin="2,0" Name="SkillSelectCB" ItemsSource="{Binding PotentialChildren}" />
                <TextBox Margin="2,0" Width="50" Visibility="{Binding ??}" />
                <Button Margin="2,0" Content="Add" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

This is actually in a HierarchicalDataTemplate, the example above is very minimal. The "Add" `Button` will add new children to the ViewModel for the `TreeView` based on what's selected in the `ComboBox`. And the visibility is the `TextBox` will change depending on some property of the `ComboBox`'s SelectedItem.

Comment: what did you try? you should post your code...

Comment: @makc I'm not sure what to try. I think it can be done with the Converter but I can't seem to find an example anywhere. I've included the Xaml for the `TreeView` if that helps.

Comment: @makc Ahh nevermind I got it, it was easier than I thought, I must have been too tired last night.

Comment: I am glad a didnt help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the Xaml for the `TextBox`:

```
<TextBox Margin="2,0"Width="50" Visibility="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=SkillSelectCB, Converter={StaticResource SkillToVisibilityConverter}}" />
```

And the Converter:

```
public class SkillToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var s = (Skill)value;
        return (s == null || !s.Specialized) ? "Hidden" : "Visible";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```